# Ubuntu 20.04 random volume changes

Tags: 20.04

It changes whenever I pause the video/play the video. Tell me how I can provide more information. What config you would like me to provide.

Comment: what video program are you using? is this happening only on this specific program? is this happening only when you pause and play the video?

Comment: Same here... After upgrading to 20.4 the volume randomly changes (increases). This happens in all programs - I mainly use Firefox, Gnome-Console and Vscode though....

Comment: Could you add the output of `journalctl -p warning | grep audio` and `inxi -SMA -! 31 -y 80` (probably you'll need to install [inxi](https://smxi.org/docs/inxi.htm) first).

Comment: grep: invalid option -- 'S'

Comment: Th problem is not happening since upgrade from oct 15 (yesterday). I will update the thread if the problem comes back.

Comment: @PabloBianchi: It needs to be `inxi -SMA --no-host -y 80` now. `-! 31` doesn't work anymore in `inxi` 3.1.07. (Kubuntu 20.10)